# Filter by title content and meta key at the same time

Tags: wp-query

Using:

```
$query = new WP_Query();
```

How do I filter to get records with titles OR content OR meta keys which contain a part of a string.

I currently have

```
$args=array(
          'order'=>'asc',
          'post_type' => $type,
          'post_status' => 'publish',
          'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                        'key'     => 'my_meta_key',
                        'value'   => sanitize_text_field($_GET["search"]),
                        'compare' => 'LIKE'
                    )
                ),
          'posts_per_page' => -1,
          'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
```

Which is currently working perfectly but does not obvious filter by title and content as well.

Comment: Please note, this site ***is*** about WordPress, adding that your question is about WordPress is therefor useless. Also note, if you had debugging turned on, you would have noticed that `caller_get_posts` is depreciated for many many years now and should not be used. You should be using `ignore_sticky_posts`

Answer (score 2):

Such condition is impossible to express in current WP API. You can use search for title/content matches and meta query for LIKE matches on post meta, but there is no way to establish OR relationship between the two.

The closest API way would be two–stage query where you query IDs for two sets of results (one for search, one for meta), then query full data for their combination.

Outside of that it is realm custom SQL. Not impossible, but relatively hard to write and harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response.......I have decided to settle for searching by just the title WITH a like comparison.....can you please point me in the right direction

Comment: See [Search Parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Search_Parameter) in Codex.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a solution to look for multiple keywords that can be mixed in either post title, description AND/OR one or several metas, so I made my own addition to the search function.

All you is to add the following code in *function.php*, and whenever you us the 's' argument in WP_Query() and want it to search in one or several as well you simply add a 's_meta_keys' argument that is an array of the meta(s) key you want to search in:

```
/************************************************************************\
|**                                                                    **|
|**  Allow WP_Query() search function to look for multiple keywords    **|
|**  in metas in addition to post_title and post_content               **|
|**                                                                    **|
|**  By rAthus @ Arkanite                                              **|
|**  Created: 2020-08-18                                               **|
|**  Updated: 2020-08-19                                               **|
|**                                                                    **|
|**  Just use the usual 's' argument and add a 's_meta_keys' argument  **|
|**  containing an array of the meta(s) key you want to search in :)   **|
|**                                                                    **|
|**  Example :                                                         **|
|**                                                                    **|
|**  $args = array(                                                    **|
|**      'numberposts'  => -1,                                         **|
|**      'post_type' => 'post',                                        **|
|**      's' => $MY_SEARCH_STRING,                                     **|
|**      's_meta_keys' => array('META_KEY_1','META_KEY_2');            **|
|**      'orderby' => 'date',                                          **|
|**      'order'   => 'DESC',                                          **|
|**  );                                                                **|
|**  $posts = new WP_Query($args);                                     **|
|**                                                                    **|
\************************************************************************/
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_search_query'); // add the special search fonction on each get_posts query (this includes WP_Query())
function my_search_query($query) {
    if ($query->is_search() and $query->query_vars and $query->query_vars['s'] and $query->query_vars['s_meta_keys']) { // if we are searching using the 's' argument and added a 's_meta_keys' argument
        global $wpdb;
        $search = $query->query_vars['s']; // get the search string
        $ids = array(); // initiate array of martching post ids per searched keyword
        foreach (explode(' ',$search) as $term) { // explode keywords and look for matching results for each
            $term = trim($term); // remove unnecessary spaces
            if (!empty($term)) { // check the the keyword is not empty
                $query_posts = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_status='publish' AND ((post_title LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (post_content LIKE '%%%s%%'))", $term, $term); // search in title and content like the normal function does
                $ids_posts = [];
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($query_posts);
                if ($wpdb->last_error)
                    die($wpdb->last_error);
                foreach ($results as $result)
                    $ids_posts[] = $result->ID; // gather matching post ids
                $query_meta = [];
                foreach($query->query_vars['s_meta_keys'] as $meta_key) // now construct a search query the search in each desired meta key
                    $query_meta[] = $wpdb->prepare("meta_key='%s' AND meta_value LIKE '%%%s%%'", $meta_key, $term);
                $query_metas = $wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->postmeta} WHERE ((".implode(') OR (',$query_meta)."))");
                $ids_metas = [];
                $results = $wpdb->get_results($query_metas);
                if ($wpdb->last_error)
                    die($wpdb->last_error);
                foreach ($results as $result)
                    $ids_metas[] = $result->post_id; // gather matching post ids
                $merged = array_merge($ids_posts,$ids_metas); // merge the title, content and meta ids resulting from both queries
                $unique = array_unique($merged); // remove duplicates
                if (!$unique)
                    $unique = array(0); // if no result, add a "0" id otherwise all posts will be returned
                $ids[] = $unique; // add array of matching ids into the main array
            }
        }
        if (count($ids)>1)
            $intersected = call_user_func_array('array_intersect',$ids); // if several keywords keep only ids that are found in all keywords' matching arrays
        else
            $intersected = $ids[0]; // otherwise keep the only matching ids array
        $unique = array_unique($intersected); // remove duplicates
        if (!$unique)
            $unique = array(0); // if no result, add a "0" id otherwise all posts will be returned
        unset($query->query_vars['s']); // unset normal search query
        $query->set('post__in',$unique); // add a filter by post id instead
    }
}
```

Example use:

```
$search= "kewords to search";

$args = array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    's' => $search,
    's_meta_keys' => array('short_desc','tags');
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);

$posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

This example will look for the keywords "kewords to search" in post titles, descriptions, and meta keys 'short_desc' and 'tags'.

Keywords can be found in one or several of the fileds, in any order, it will return any post that has all the keywords in any of the designated fields.

You can obiously force the search in a list of meta keys you include in the fonction and get rid of the extra agruments if you want ALL search queries to include these meta keys :)

Hope that will help anyone who face the same issue I did!

Comment: Interesting approach. But `call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $ids);` will cause non-intersecting ids to be skipped, so posts matching some search words won't be shown. `call_user_func_array( 'array_merge', $ids )` would be more correct, I verified this by testing.

Comment: That behaviour was intented actually, if the user searches for "red apple", I want the function to return posts that will contain "red" AND "apple" and that's what `'array_intersect'` does. Using `'array_merge'` will cause the function to return all posts that contain only "red" or only "apple" as well, which I believe you don't want in mosts cases, unless you add some code that will also allow to order results showing posts with the most keywords first, but that would probably make the whole thing quite heavly :/

Answer (score 0):

I think this code can do what you want:

```
$q1 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    's' => get_search_query()
));
$q2 = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
           'key' => '_sku',
           'value' => get_search_query(),
           'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
     )
));
$merged = array_merge( $q1, $q2 );
$post_ids = array();
foreach( $merged as $item ) {
    $post_ids[] = $item->ID;
}
$unique = array_unique($post_ids);
if(!$unique){
    $unique=array('0');
}
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => '10',
    'post__in' => $unique,
    'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to tack on

```
's' => get_search_query()
```

to your existing query, no? As in:

```
$args=array(
      'order'=>'asc',
      'post_type' => $type,
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                    'key'     => 'my_meta_key',
                    'value'   => sanitize_text_field($_GET["search"]),
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            ),
      's' => get_search_query(),
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'caller_get_posts'=> 1);
```

I use pretty much this exact approach to a database search where you can search last name or first name (stored as custom fields), and then choose to add in keywords which searches post content within posts that match the custom fields.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it using regular expressions and the filters `posts_join` and `posts_search` (documented [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get_posts/#hooks)):

The following code lets you search for posts of type `my_post_type` by trying to match the search term against the usual fields specified by the [post_search_columns](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_search_columns/) filter (title, excerpt and content), AND it also matches against the post meta `my_meta_key`.

```
add_action(
    'pre_get_posts',
    function( $query ) {

        if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
            return;
        }

        if ( 'my_post_type' != $query->query['post_type'] ) {
            return;
        }

        // HERE YOU CAN ADD ADDITIONAL CONDITIONS TO $query IF YOU NEED TO

        if ( $query->is_search() ) {
        
            $term = trim( $query->query_vars['s'] );
            
            add_filter(
                'posts_search',
                function( $search, $wp_query ) use ( $term ) {
                    global $wpdb;

                    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_search() && preg_match( '/\(wp_posts.post_title LIKE \'(\{[0-9a-f]+\})([^{]+)\{/', $search, $matches ) ) {
                        $delimiter = $matches[ 1 ];
                        $term = $matches[ 2 ];

                        $search = str_replace(
                            "({$wpdb->posts}.post_title",
                            "(custom_search_meta.meta_key = 'my_meta_key' AND custom_search_meta.meta_value LIKE '{$delimiter}{$term}{$delimiter}') OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_title" ,
                            $search
                        );
                    }

                    return $search;
                },
                11,
                2
            );

            add_filter(
                'posts_join',
                function( $join, $wp_query ) {
                    global $wpdb;
                    if ( $wp_query->is_main_query() && $wp_query->is_search() ) {
                        $join = "$join INNER JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS custom_search_meta ON ( wp_posts.ID = custom_search_meta.post_id )";
                    }

                    return $join;
                },
                11,
                2
            );
            

        } // end if search
    } // end pre_get_posts hook
);
```

It's ugly but it works...